# How to filter fields returned after search in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming I have a documents indexed like the following:

```
{
    category: "fruits",
    items: [
        {
            name: "Apple",
            shape: "Round",
            color: "red"
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Assuming I want to search across all the fields but only return either:

1. `items` field only
2. `items` field, but only the `name` and `shape` fields (not the `color` field in the list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter in/out fields from the `source` (entire document) by specifying the reserved [`_source` field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-source-filtering.html):

To only retrieve the `items`, then specify a filter like so:

```
{
    "_source" : "items.*",
    "query" : ...
}
```

To retrieve the specific `items` of interest, then there are multiple ways, but if you know them all (rather than needing wildcard *exclude* support):

```
{
    "_source" : [ "items.name", "items.shape" ],
    "query" : ...
}
```

Alternatively, if it wasn't so simple:

```
{
    "_source" : {
        "include" : [ "items.*" ],
        "exclude" : [ "items.color" ]
    }
    "query" : ...
}
```

This gives the most flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict using field in query.. Like

```
   {
    Query:{
                 Bla bla bla
                 }, 
   Fields :["items . name", "items.shape"] 
     }
```

Comment: That restricts the fields to _search_ rather than what is being returned.

Comment: If you mention fields inside query means ly restrictions on fields to be search... If you mention outside it Ll restrict the fields to be returned...

Comment: Interesting, I had only ever used it for the search restriction and I had no idea that it worked for both. That's pretty neat! +1